# React sub component can't be clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create a "Title" component in a header. When you click on the title component a header should pop up with buttons that allow for bold, underline etc. This is similar to a component in a google site that I liked.

Here the Header component contains the Title Component, which contains the TitleToolbar. The title toolbar is only visible when you click on the title. The trouble is that the buttons on the toolbar don't work. I have tried to play with focus on the title tool bar but to no avail. I want to use the title toolbar and the title components at the same time.

[image]

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-grass-uhwb51)

Code snippet for the subcomponent.

```js
import { Box, Button } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";

function TitleToolbar({ clickOnBold }) {
  // console.log("clickOnBold", clickOnBold);
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        background: "#c0e1eb",
        height: "40px",
        width: "100%",
        position: "absolute",
        textAlign: "left",
        top: "0px",
        left: "0px"
      }}
    >
      <Button onClick={clickOnBold}>B</Button>
      <Button onClick={() => {}}> U</Button>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default TitleToolbar;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems causing this behavior:

- The style applied to the `Box` which contains your buttons is causing them to be not  clickable. If you remove the "position: absolute", they'll become clickable. If you want them to be above the `TextField`, change the rendering order.
- After fixing the previous problem, the `onBlur` event of your `TextField` is called before the `onClick` of your `Button`. So, it looks like you're clicking the button, but you're actually unfocusing the field, hiding the button and then, it can't be clicked. If you remove the `onBlur`, the function `clickOnBlur` is called when your click on the button. You may need to find a different solution for hiding the buttons again.

You can see a working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-bird-bf5hjd?file=/src/Title.js

Comment: Thanks for an alternate approach.

My intention for keeping the TitleToolbar as a subcomponent was to prevent the onBlur from being called from within a child of the parent component. This in turn requires absolute position.

Do you have any thoughts on how both the Title and TitleToolbar component could be made to work together? What's an alternative to using the onBlur function for dealing focus and hiding/showing the TitleToolbar component?

Comment: In your solution I moved the blurHandler to the Box that contains the TitleToolbar and the TextField. The blurHanlder gets called even when I click on the TitleToolbar. Removing the blurHandler removes all focus related processing as well and the TitleToolbar doesn't hide either.

Comment: You can keep the TitleToolbar as a subcomponent, that isn't a problem. The problem is that the `onBlur` prevents the `onClick` from being called. So, when you click the button, the `onBlur` is called, and that prevents the `onClick` from the Button from being called

Comment: Understood. However, onBlur is necessary to hide/show the component. How else can I show or hide the component?

Comment: @NRS2000 using a debounce could solve the problem. I used a simple `setTimeout` on this sandbox and were able to click the button, because the button doesn't get hidden immediately after unfocusing. Check it out: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-goldwasser-ox8ldq

Comment: Thanks for a very interesting idea. It doesn't help me directly, but suggests another possibility. I can setup a mouseover event and not change focus if it's over the TitleToolbar. I will try that out.